# Pure CSS3 Navigation Menu child level appears behind parent level

Tags: css, z-index

I have a Pure CSS3 Navigation Menu where child level appears behind parent level.
Tried to resolve it by playing with z-index and other elements for 5 days now.
Thanks in advance!
Here's the HTML(direction RTL):

```
                                            <div id="MainNavMenu">
                                <div id="main_navigation" class="blue main-menu "><!--  START -->
                                    <ul>
                                            <li class="main_list_item"><a class="main_list_link" href="#">Marketing</a>
                                                    <ul>
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">NPA</a>
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">PMN</a>
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">NML</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">Document Library</a></li> <!-- Third Level -->
                                                            </ul>
                                                       </li> 
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">Cataloges</a></li>
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">Price lists</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                            </li> 

                                            <li class="main_list_item"><a class="main_list_link" href="#">פיתוח</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="doclib.html">Document Library</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="our-team.html">Project Management</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">QA</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">Administration</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">R&D Mechanics</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">Catalog</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">Mtb</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">Itbs</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">Eit</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                            </li> 
                                            <li class="main_list_item"><a class="main_list_link" href="#">משהו</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="doclib.html">מכונות</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">ליב</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="our-team.html">MSG</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">Type</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">DIff</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                    </li>


                                                    <li><a href="doclib.html">בטיחות</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">נהלי בג"ס</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="our-team.html">מפרטים</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">טפסים</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">איכות הסביבה</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">בטיחות וגיהות</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">בריאות וארגונומיה</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">מידע ותקנים</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="career.html">MSDS</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                    </li>


                                                    <li><a href="doclib.html">משק ובטחון</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">ספריות מסמכים</a></li>
                                                            </ul>       
                                                    </li>

                                                    <li><a href="doclib.html">אבטחת איכות</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">מדריכי משתמש</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">מפרטים מחלקתיים</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">דו"חות מנטי</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">תעודות איכות</a></li>
                                                            </ul>       
                                                    </li>

                                                    <li><a href="doclib.html">רכש</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">ספריות מסמכים</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">חוזי ספק</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">TTR פלדות</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">FDT השחזה</a></li>
                                                            </ul>       
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>   
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="main_list_item"><a class="main_list_link" href="#">חברה שלי</a>
                                                   <ul>
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">ספר טלפונים</a></li> <!-- SECOND LEVEL MENU --> 
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">טלפונים חשובים</a></li>
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">פתיחת תקלת מחשוב</a></li>
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">פינת נוסטלגיה</a></li>
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">ימי הולדת</a></li>
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">שערי מטבע</a></li>
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">המתבח של ישקר</a></li>
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">אירועים</a></li>
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">ספריות מסמכים</a></li>
                                                       <li><a href="about-us.html">משאבי אנוש</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">טפסים</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">מסמכי ביטוח</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">מידע והטבות</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">נהלים</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">הודעות</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="about-us.html">אירועים</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                       </li>
                                                   </ul>
                                            </li>
                                    </ul>
                                        </div> <!-- MAIN NAVIGATION END -->

                                </div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
         /**************************************
                                Navigation Menu
                                ***************************************/
                                #MainNavMenu 
                                { 
                                     left: 1040px; 
                                     top: 70px; 
                                     position: absolute; 
                                     width: -moz-fit-content;
                                    width: -webkit-fit-content;
                                    width: fit-content;
                                    margin: auto;
                                     height: 18px;
                                     z-index:3;
                                } 
                                #main_navigation{
                                    width: -moz-fit-content;
                                    width: -webkit-fit-content;
                                    width: fit-content;
                                    margin: auto;
                                    font-size:8px;height:20px;float:right;
                                    outline:none;
                                    margin-bottom:250px;
                                    box-shadow:1px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                                    opacity: 1;
                                    border-radius:5px;
                                    }

                                .main-menu{position:relative;z-index:7;font-family: 'Ariel', tahoma, serif;letter-spacing:0pt; solid;}
                                .main-menu ul li a, .main-menu ul li a:link, .main-menu ul li a:visited{border-bottom:4pt solid transparent;padding-bottom:1px}
                                .main-menu ul {
                                    margin:0;
                                    padding:0px;
                                    list-style-type:none;
                                    z-index:5;
                                    border-radius:5px;
                                }

                                .main-menu ul li {
                                    position:relative;
                                    display:inline;
                                    float:right;
                                    z-index:4;
                                }
                                /*Second level settings*/
                                .main-menu ul li > ul {
                                    z-index:2;
                                    visibility:hidden;
                                    display:inline;
                                    opacity:0;
                                    padding:0px;margin:0px;
                                    position:absolute;
                                    /*width: -moz-fit-content;
                                    width: -webkit-fit-content;
                                    width: fit-content;*/
                                    width: 150px;
                                    top:25px;
                                    right:40px;
                                    color:#FFFFFF;
                                    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                                    -moz-transition:width 0.3s ease-in-out;
                                    -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                                    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                                }
                                /*on hover over second level - third level appears*/
                                .main-menu ul li ul li:hover > ul {
                                    display:block;
                                    visibility:visible;
                                    right:50px;
                                    top: 15px;
                                    opacity: 1;
                                    z-index: 9999;
                                }

                                .main-menu ul li:hover > ul {
                                    display:block;
                                    visibility:visible;
                                    right:0px;
                                    display:block;
                                    opacity:1;
                                }
                                .main_list_item {
                                    height:20px;
                                    z-index:0;
                                }
                                .main-menu ul li a.main_list_link,.main-menu ul li a.main_list_link:link{
                                    line-height:20px;
                                    text-shadow:none;
                                    font-size:12px; 
                                    text-transform:uppercase;   
                                }
                                .main-menu ul li > a {
                                    display:block;
                                    text-decoration:none;
                                    overflow:hidden;
                                    padding:0px 15px;
                                    border-radius:3px;
                                }
                                * html .main-menu ul li a {
                                    display:inline-block;
                                }

                                .main-menu ul li ul li {
                                    display:list-item;
                                    float:right;
                                    border-left:none!important;
                                    color:#FFFFFF;  
                                    padding:0px;margin:0px;
                                }
                                .main-menu ul li ul li a {
                                    margin:0px;
                                    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                                    -moz-transition:width 0.3s ease-in-out;
                                    -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                                    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;

                                    }

                                .main-menu ul li ul li{
                                     -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                                    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                                    -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                                    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                                    border-bottom:solid 1px #ececec;
                                    width:100%;

                                    }

                                .main-menu ul ul {
                                    background:#FFFFFF;
                                    border:1px solid #e0e0e0;
                                    -moz-box-shadow:0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
                                    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
                                    box-shadow:0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
                                    z-index:9;
                                    color:#707070;  
                                }
                                .main-menu ul ul li a,.main-menu ul ul li a:visited,.main-menu ul ul li a:link {
                                    height:100%;
                                    text-transform: capitalize;
                                    margin-right:0px!important;
                                    margin-left:0px!important;
                                    font-size:12px; 
                                    color:#707070;      
                                    z-index:10;
                                    background-color: #FFFFFF ;
                                }
                                /*TEMP*/

                                /*TEMP*/

                                .main-menu ul ul li:hover > a{
                                    cursor:pointer;
                                    text-decoration:none!important;
                                    padding-right:30px;
                                    right: 40px;
                                    z-index:11;
                                }

                                .main-menu ul ul  li > a:after{
                                    content:"";
                                    opacity:0;
                                    position:absolute;
                                    right:20px;top:26px;
                                    width: 0; 
                                    height: 0; 
                                    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
                                    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
                                    border-right:5px solid #FEFEFE;     
                                    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
                                    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
                                    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
                                    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
                                    z-index:12;
                                }

                                /*arrow pointer inside menu item*/
                                .main-menu ul ul li:hover > a:after{
                                content:"";
                                opacity:1;
                                position:absolute;
                                right:0px;top:5px;
                                width: 0; 
                                height: 0; 
                                border-right:5px solid #FEFEFE; 
                                }

                                .main-menu ul ul ul {
                                    position:absolute;
                                    right: 100px;
                                    top :20px;

                                }


                                /***********
                                Menu Color
                                ************/
                                /* BLUE */

                                .blue{
                                background:#148cfc; 
                                /*border:2px solid #ffd017;*/ /*yellow border*/
                                }
                                .blue ul ul{
                                border-top:2px solid #ffd017;
                                width:99%;
                                }

                                .blue ul ul li:hover > a{
                                    text-decoration:none!important;
                                    color:#FFF!important;
                                    background:#148cfc;
                                    padding-right:30px;
                                    text-shadow:1px 0px 0px #3080b0;
                                }
                                .blue ul li a{
                                color:#FFFFFF;
                                }
                                .blue ul li > a:hover,.blue ul li:hover > a{
                                    color:#ffd017!important;    
                                }
                                /*menu items separator*/
                                .blue .main_list_item:after{
                                content:"";
                                z-index:-1;
                                position:absolute;
                                border-right:1px solid #e9e9e9;
                                box-shadow:1px 0px 0px #057794;
                                height:15px;
                                top:3px;
                                background:#FFF;
                                }
                                /*FIXING border */
                                .main_list_item:first-child:after{
                                border-right:none;
                                }
                                /************************************** 
                                End Of Navigation Menu
                                ***************************************/
```

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle..

Comment: Please refer http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpbqH

Comment: The child's z index is greater than the parent. it works good..What is it that you would like to change?

Comment: it doesn't work well because when you hover over an item which has a child item (3rd level) you can see that it shows behind the parent. I need it to be shown in front. Go to the second item from the left and walk through the items inside. You can see that the ones that have a child it will be shown just in behind them.

Comment: Can Anyone save the day?